# Change order of elements in mobile view using css

Tags: css, responsive-design

I need to change the order of elements using css in mobile view. Please refer to the code below.

```
<div class="container">
  <aside>
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pulvinar sapien a erat lacinia, in consequat metus tincidunt. Morbi rhoncus, odio ac im</p>
    <a href="">Link</a>
  </aside>
  <span>This line should come after heading.</span>
</div>
```

I want to move the span right after the heading in mobile view.

This is how I want in mobile devices:
[image]

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

aside {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <aside>
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pulvinar sapien a erat lacinia, in consequat metus tincidunt. Morbi rhoncus, odio ac im</p>
    <a href="">Link</a>
  </aside>
  <span>This line should come after heading.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you alter the HTML at all?

Comment: No, cannot alter HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this by switching classes using media queries

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .show-mob {
    display: block;
  }
  .show {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <aside>
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <span class="show-mob">This line should come after heading.</span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pulvinar sapien a erat lacinia, in consequat metus tincidunt. Morbi rhoncus, odio ac im</p>
    <a href="">Link</a>
  </aside>
  <span class="show">This line should come after heading.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```
<div class="container">
    <aside>
    <h2>Heading</h2>

    <span id="spn1" style="display:none">This line should come after heading.</span>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pulvinar 
 sapien a erat lacinia, in consequat metus tincidunt. Morbi rhoncus, odio ac 
 im</p>
  <a href="">Link</a>
  </aside>
  <span id="spn2">This line should come after heading.</span>
</div>
```

For mobile view use media query

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   #spn1{
 display:block;
}
 #spn2{
 display:none;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to change it only with CSS
If you can use jquery you can try to use the .append() function and something like that

```
function checkPosition() {
if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
    //...
} else {
    //...
}
});
```

if you dont have the chance to use jQuery you need to restructure your HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<div class="container">
  <aside>
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <span class="show-on-mobile">This line should come after heading.</span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pulvinar sapien a erat lacinia, in consequat metus tincidunt. Morbi rhoncus, odio ac im</p>
    <a href="">Link</a>
  </aside>
  <span class="hide-on-mobile">This line should come after heading.</span>
</div>
```

and for CSS:

```
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

aside {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.show-on-mobile {
  display:none;

}

@media (max-width: 575px) { 
  .hide-on-mobile {
    display:none;
  }
  .show-on-mobile {
    display:block;
    float:none;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottomn:30px
  }
}
```

[EXAMPLE](https://codepen.io/desig9stein/pen/ZKbado)

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

aside {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.container h2{position:relative; margin-bottom:20px;}
.container p{padding-top:30px;}
span {
  width: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:60px;
  padding:10px;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <aside>
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pulvinar sapien a erat lacinia, in consequat metus tincidunt. Morbi rhoncus, odio ac im</p>
    <a href="">Link</a>
  </aside>
  <span>This line should come after heading.</span>
</div>
```

Please try like this